# Magento 2 : Social Login via Rest Api

Tags: magento2, api, customer-account, webapi

I need to create a user account using social network via the API.

I have created via `native iOS application` that hooks into magento 2 store API. However, I can not find a way to create an account using any of social extensions. 
They add buttons however they do not expose any functionality over rest API for creating accounts or login.

Comment: Did you reached for the solution?

Comment: Still looking - Mostly likely will need to code the full implementation

Comment: Do you have an Idean, how to get the token after login with social ? review this `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175480/get-token-authentication-for-customer-logged-with-facebook-twitter-magento-2`

Comment: You can follow this guide: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-social-login-in-magento-2/
to add Social login to your site.

Comment: Any solution for login and create a customer account API for Facebook and Google ?

Comment: Any solution on this @justacoder?

Answer (score 1):

1) First Create webapi.xml declare url, interface and method

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

    <route url="/V1/fetch/sociallogin" method="POST">
        <service class="HIT\Customer\Api\SocialLoginCustomerInterface" method="socialLogin"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>

</routes>
```

2) create di.xml for dependency injection

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="HIT\Customer\Api\SocialLoginCustomerInterface" type="HIT\Customer\Model\SocialLoginCustomer" />

</config>
```

3) create social login interface SocialLoginCustomerInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace HIT\Customer\Api;

interface SocialLoginCustomerInterface
{
      /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function socialLogin();
}
```

4) create SocialLoginCustomer.php for logic

```
<?php

namespace HIT\Customer\Model;

use HIT\Customer\Api\SocialLoginCustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;

class SocialLoginCustomer implements SocialLoginCustomerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $_request;
    /**
     * @var EncryptorInterface
     */
    protected $_encryptor;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;
    /**
     * @var RequestFactory
     */
    protected $requestFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerExtractor
     */
    protected $customerExtractor;

    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @var Config\Source\BrandOptions
     */
    protected $brandOptions;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository
     *
     */
    protected $customerRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory
     */
    protected $addressFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection
     */
    protected $customerCollection;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $_resource;

    /**
     * CreateCustomer constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param EncryptorInterface $encryptor
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param RequestFactory $requestFactory
     * @param CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param Config\Source\MotherTongue $brandOptions
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor $encryptor,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        RequestFactory $requestFactory,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        Config\Source\MotherTongue $brandOptions,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $customerCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_encryptor = $encryptor;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->requestFactory = $requestFactory;
        $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->brandOptions = $brandOptions;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
        $this->customerCollection = $customerCollection;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * @return false|string
     */
    public function socialLogin()
    {
        $customerInfo = $this->_request->getContent();
        if($customerInfo){
            $customerInfo = (array) json_decode($customerInfo);
        }
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->_resource->getTableName('social_login');
        $data = array();
        $diff = array_diff_key(['firstname' => 1, 'lastname' => 1, 'email' => 1, 'customer_telephone' => 1,'social_id' => 1], $customerInfo);
        if ($customerInfo && count($diff) == 0) {

            $result = $connection->fetchOne("SELECT `customer_id` FROM ".$tableName." WHERE `social_id`='".$customerInfo['social_id']."'");

            if($result){
                $customerObjModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',$result)->getFirstItem();
                $customerObj = (object)$customerObjModel->getData();

                $customerDetails = array(
                    'customer_id' => $customerObj->entity_id,
                    'firstname' => $customerObj->firstname,
                    'lastname' =>  $customerObj->lastname,
                    'email' => $customerObj->email
                );
                $data['status'] = "true";
                $data['msg'] = 'Successfully logged in.';
                $data['customer_info'] =$customerDetails;
            }else{
                $customerData = [
                    'firstname' => $customerInfo['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $customerInfo['lastname'],
                    'email' => $customerInfo['email']
                ];

                $request = $this->requestFactory->create();
                $request->setParams($customerData);

                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $request);
                    $customer->setWebsiteId(1);
                    if (isset($customerInfo['customer_telephone'])) {
                        $customer->setCustomAttribute('customer_telephone', $customerInfo['customer_telephone']);
                    }
                    $customerModel = $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

                    $customerDetails = array(
                        'customer_id' => $customerModel->getId(),
                        'firstname' => $customerModel->getFirstname(),
                        'lastname' =>  $customerModel->getLastname(),
                        'email' => $customerModel->getEmail()
                    );

                    $result = $connection->query("INSERT INTO ".$tableName." (`customer_id`, `type`, `social_id`) VALUES (".$customerModel->getId().",'".$customerInfo['type']."','".$customerInfo['social_id']."')");
                    $data['status'] = "true";
                    $data['msg'] = 'Successfully Registered With Us.';
                    $data['customer_info'] =$customerDetails;
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $data['status'] = "false";
                    $data['msg'] = $e->getMessage();

                }
        }

        } else {
            $data['status'] = "false";
            $data['msg'] = 'Missing Params';
        }

        echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );// str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($data)); 
        exit();
    }
}
```

5) create table social_login fields are `id`, `customer_id`, `type`, `social_id`, `created_at`

Comment: Why you have used `exit()` after end of code? I don't get that?

Answer (score 0):

At first create a custom rest api with below route. you can follow this link:
https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/ to create custom res api.

```
<!-- ws: social login -->
<route url="/V1/customrestapi/login" method="POST">
    <service class="PackageName\CustomRestApi\Api\SocialloginInterface" method="socialLogin"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Then in the **socialLogin** method pass the social data as array.Here you can put your logic as shown below code.

```
/**
* Copyright 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

namespace PackageName\CustomRestApi\Model;

use PackageName\CustomRestApi\Api\SocialloginInterface;
/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the calculator service contract.
 */
class Sociallogin implements SocialloginInterface
{

protected $_storeManager;
protected $_scopeConfig;
protected $_objectManager;
protected $_customerFactory;


public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_objectManager =  $objectManager;
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

/**
 * Check Login.
 *
 * @api
 * @param string[] $data The array of strings to socialLogin.
 * @return $this
 */
public function socialLogin($data) {
    // json array for data should be {"data":{"email":"test@gmail.com","password":"password","type":"fb/gp","socialId":"","socialToken":"","firstName":"","lastName":"","dob":"","gender":""}}
    // type is used to identify social media facebook or google+
       if($data['type']=='fb'){
           // facbook login logic goes here
        }
       elseif($data['type']=='gp'){
           // google plus login logic goes here
       }
}
```

Comment: Any solution for login and create a customer account API for Facebook and Google ?

Comment: Just use the above given method and then you can create customer programatically.

Comment: Have created for login Facebook and Google for Login and Registration Rest API? If you have done. could you please share the code ? So helpful for me.

Comment: I have no access of code right now. You can post your issue what you have tried.

Comment: I have created as per your answer API and created simple function not added full code. But I can't able to identify in code where i am login in facebook or google.

Comment: If you have idea then just post your code. Hope i help for same. Thanks.

Comment: any solution on this. If yes then please share code @KirtiNariya